# Return view (Table) from controller laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

i am returning table view from controller function and its working (through ajax). but want to use foreach in above the 'tr' tag. but don't know how to use it.

1. Function for return Ajax response

   ```
    public function displaySearch(Request $request)
        {
           $result = Team::where('name', $request->somthing)
                    ->orwhere('order_id', $request->filter)->get();

            $data = $this->make_ui($result);
            return $data;
        }
   ```
2. Private Function for Make UI

   ```
   private function make_ui($result){
             $data='';

             foreach($result as $c){
             $data.='<div class="table-responsive">
               <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
               <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>Action</th>
                   <th>ID</th>
                   <th>Date</th>
                   <th>Description</th>
               </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   <tr class="gradeX">
                       <td>'. $c->id .'</td>
                       <td>'. $c->order_id .'</td>
                       <td>'. $c->name .'</td>
                       <td>'. $c->role .'</td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
               <tfoot>
               <tr>
                   <th>Action</th>
                   <th>ID</th>
                   <th>Date</th>
                   <th>Description</th>
               </tr>
               </tfoot>
           </table>
       </div>';
   }
     return $data;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plz use this it`s work for me

```
private function make_ui($result){
          $data='<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';

          foreach($result as $c){
          $data.='
                <tr class="gradeX">
                    <td>'. $c->id .'</td>
                    <td>'. $c->order_id .'</td>
                    <td>'. $c->name .'</td>
                    <td>'. $c->role .'</td>
                </tr>
            ';
           }
          $data .= '</tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>';
  return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to concat them separately. Though I am not sure if it's the best solution or not. **you can try like below**:

```
private function make_ui($result){     
    $data.='<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Action</th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';
    foreach($result as $c){
        $data.='<tr class="gradeX">
                    <td>'. $c->id .'</td>
                    <td>'. $c->order_id .'</td>
                    <td>'. $c->name .'</td>
                    <td>'. $c->role .'</td>
                </tr>';
    }
    $data.='</tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>';
    return $data;
}
```